# Is it possible to compile libCurl with SSH support using vc8?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, curl, ssh

I am working on an application, implemented in VC++ 2008 that needs to use sftp through libCurl.  In order for this to happen, libCurl needs to be built with ssh support.  The problem is that, unlike the mingw makefile, the makefile for vc8 does not have target configurations to build with SSH support.  Does anyone know what needs to be done to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same answer and found this [document](http://curl.askapache.com/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2008.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

You can also follow the PHP-for-win's instructions:

http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs/libcurl